# android : how to load haarcascade inside the raw folder in javacv?

Tags: java, android, javacv

I am new in Javacv and android and i totally don't know what to do with this error. I am trying to load the haarcascade file but unfortunately the app always crashes.

Here's my code for mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.cameraapp;


import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;





public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static String logtag = "CAMERA APP";
private Uri imageUri;
private static int TAKE_PICTURE=1;

String s ;
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView k ;

private static final int MAX_FACES = 5;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button  c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
        c.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    }
    private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){takePhoto(v);}
    };
    private void takePhoto(View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "picture.jpg");
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
         s = image.getAbsolutePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);


        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){


            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            try{
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch(Exception e){Log.e(logtag,e.toString());
            }

        try{


        String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.haarcascade_frontalface_default;
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText(uri+" "+s);

          FaceDetector s = new FaceDetector();

    s.detect(uri);      
            }catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Log.e(logtag,e.toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the facedetector class that will load the file

```
package com.example.cameraapp;


import java.io.*;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;


import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;
public class FaceDetector {



    public void detect(String XML_FILE){



        CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(XML_FILE));





}
}
```

And here is the error that I get from the logcat:

```
09-07 15:00:59.169: D/dalvikvm(1298): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K (69), 2% free 22074K/22404K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
09-07 15:00:59.396: D/skia(1298): jpeg_decoder finish successfully, L:1406, reuse 0!!!
09-07 15:00:59.420: E/dalvikvm(1298): Could not find class 'com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect$CvHaarClassifierCascade', referenced from method com.example.cameraapp.FaceDetector.detect
09-07 15:00:59.421: W/dalvikvm(1298): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1164 (Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_objdetect$CvHaarClassifierCascade;) in Lcom/example/cameraapp/FaceDetector;
09-07 15:00:59.421: D/dalvikvm(1298): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-07 15:00:59.422: D/dalvikvm(1298): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2462 at 0x06 in Lcom/example/cameraapp/FaceDetector;.detect
09-07 15:00:59.423: D/AndroidRuntime(1298): Shutting down VM
09-07 15:00:59.423: W/dalvikvm(1298): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e419a8)
09-07 15:00:59.423: W/dalvikvm(1298): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
09-07 15:00:59.423: W/System.err(1298): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect$CvHaarClassifierCascade
09-07 15:00:59.425: W/System.err(1298):     at com.example.cameraapp.FaceDetector.detect(FaceDetector.java:22)
09-07 15:00:59.425: W/System.err(1298):     at com.example.cameraapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:86)
09-07 15:00:59.425: W/System.err(1298):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5311)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3529)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3576)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/System.err(1298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 15:00:59.426: W/dalvikvm(1298): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect$CvHaarClassifierCascade
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.example.cameraapp.FaceDetector.detect(FaceDetector.java:22)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.example.cameraapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:86)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5311)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3529)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3576)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-07 15:00:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: android resources are *inside* the apk. cvLoad (or any other c-function) can't read from there (from a zipped file). you will have to copy the cascade file to sdcard or similar before, and then point cvLoad to the new location.

Comment: can you please show me on how to do that using sdcard

Comment: no idea about javacv, sorry

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/face-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/facedetect/FdActivity.java#L68

Comment: I removed the OpenCV tag because this seems to be related to JavaCV/Android and not OpenCV. Although you can call some OpenCV functions via JavaCV, JavaCV is not OpenCV.